# Can I have 2 NAT gateways on one public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC and 2 public subnet with one NAT gatway each
 and 2 private subnets. our application resides in Private subnets. 
Our application need to connect to the third party integration which is rate limited. Can I have 2 NAT gateways for each public subnets and 2 new private subnets which will route the traffic to the newly created NAT gateways ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can create any number of NAT gateways and specify in the routing table of the private subnet to allow traffic to pass through the specific NAT gateways.**